# Calculate Fibonacci series from nth term to mth term

Tags: code-challenge

Your goal is to calculate the sum of Fibonacci series from **n** th term to **m** th term (including both terms).

- No use of `/ * %` or mathematically what they are in your language of choice.
- No use of special **functions** or **code language** specialized in doing so !
- You have to produce the series yourself and not by any special function or code language.

### OUTPUT

```
#1

0 5
series : 1 1 2 3 5 8  
sum    : 20

#2

2 5
series : 2 3 5 8
sum    : 18
```

Best of luck **:]**

Comment: Question says `nth to mth (including both)`.  So `0 5` would imply 6 terms; similarly `2 5` would imply 4 terms.  Could you edit your question to make it __consistent__?

Comment: @devnull You down-voted the question ? I made an edit to my post

Comment: I only left the note.  Somebody else downvoted it.  (Perhaps because it doesn't seem fun.)

Comment: `No use of / * %` - which are useless anyway, you probably mean `+` and `-`.

Comment: @devnull how can I make this challange more fun ?

Comment: @everyone please leave suggestions to make this question more better !

Comment: If you're using a zero-indexed Fibonacci, the 0th term should be 0.

Comment: The site has 23 Fibonacci questions already. (Type `fibonacci is:question` into the search.) Did you consider giving a different number sequence a look in? :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, both examples are wrong. 1+1+2+3+5+8 does not equal 17, and 2+3+5+8 does not equal 15. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @Tal post edited anything else?

Comment: @PeterTaylor please explain...how?

Comment: "Do the same calculation as this question but tweak the output slightly" doesn't make it a different question. See Jonathan's comment. There are lots of interesting sequences in OEIS which no questions have been asked about.

Comment: This question doesn't even have an objective winning criterion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Julia

```
fib(n)=n<2?1:fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
sumfib(n,m)=sum([fib(i) for i=n:m])
```

Output examples:

```
julia> sumfib(0,5)  # 1  1  2  3  5  8
20

julia> sumfib(2,4)  # 2  3  5
10

julia> sumfib(2,5)  # 2  3  5  8
18
```

**EDIT:** Changed to fit question's fibonacci convention.

Comment: The third term is 3 and not 2, The fifth term is 8 and not 5 please fix your code!

Comment: @Mukul Kumar. Both convention actually exist (either f(0) = 0 and f(3)=2 or f(1)=1 and f(3)=3). But since you don't follow yourself the most current and modern convention, you can't ask the author of the current solution to change his/her code. I think the author shouldn't change it, and the question should allow both conventions.

Comment: Well, i think its really a matter of conventions, but i changed the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## J (35 characters)

A solution in J *with Fibonacci sequence starting at index 0 and value 0 according to most current conventions*. The slash `/` has absolutely nothing to do with mathematical operation in J.

```
(;+/)@:(+/@(!|.)@i."0)@([+i.@>:@-~)
```

For instance:

```
3 (;+/)@:(+/@(!|.)@i."0)@([+i.@>:@-~) 6
┌───────┬──┐
│2 3 5 8│18│
└───────┴──┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## Delphi

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,idglobal;
var
  i,n,m,ires:integer;
  a:TArray<integer>;
  res:string;
begin
  ires:=0;
  readln(n,m);
  SetLength(a,m+1);
  for i:=0to m+1 do
    a[i]:=iif(i<2,1,a[i-1]+a[i-2]);
  for i:=n to m do
  begin
    write(Format('%d ',[a[i]]));
    inc(ires,a[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('|'+IntToStr(ires));
end.
```

Input: `0 5`
Output: `1 1 2 3 5 8 | 20`

Input: `1 20`
Output: `1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 | 28655`

Answer (score 1):

## C

```
int fsum (int start, int end) {
    int a[2]={1,0};
    int p=1,b=1,d=0;
    for (;p<=end+2;b=!b) {
        a[b]+=a[!b];
        d=p++==start+1?a[b]:d;
    }
    return a[!b]-d;
}
```

To make it more interesting, I've decided to see if I could a) use a static amount of memory, and b) produce the requested sum without actually adding up the [n..m] elements.
So my code doesn't print out all the elements (since it wasn't required), but produces the correct result nevertheless.